# Run Java JAR file in background

Tags: terminal, java, windows-terminal, high-dpi, jdownloader

I have a `.jar` file that acts weird with hdpi screens. When I run it directly by double-clicking on it, the text is very small and blurry, as if it wasn't hdpi-aware. But if I open my terminal and run it from there with `java -jar MyJar.jar`, it now scales the text correctly. Unfortunately, as a side effect, it also spits out logs, and dies when the terminal is closed.

Trying to set hdpi settings for `java.exe` in the Compatibility section in the properties doesn't seem to do anything.

Is there a way I can run the the `.jar` file from my terminal without having it spit logs and block my terminal?

Thank you for your time.

---

The `.jar` file in question is from the Other section of [JDownloader2](https://jdownloader.org/jdownloader2) download page, if it matters.

The terminal I'm using is the new Windows Terminal, and the shells I tried include MSYS2 and CMD - both of which leave logs in stdout/stderr and block.

Comment: Which Java version are you using? Is it possible that you have more than one JRE installed?

Comment: @harrymc Presumably the latest, since I set environment variables such as `$JAVA_HOME` and such. But I do have a variety of JDKs: 1.8 and 17-19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the `.jar` extension is linked in the registry to
one JRE version, while another JRE version is in the PATH from which
executes `jar.exe`.

It seems like the version in the PATH doesn't handle well the screen DPI.

You may check the version used in the PATH by running
*Control Panel > System > Advanced system settings >
Environment Variables...* for both user and System.

You may check the `.jar` using `regedit` at the registry key
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jar` and presumably
`HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\jarfile\shell\open\command`.

Comment: The version in PATH is JDK 19, so it should be fine with hdpi screens. As for registry keys, `HKCR\.jar` doesn't exist, while `HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command` points to JDK 1.8. However, changing the hdpi settings for JDK 1.8 `javaw.exe` doesn't seem to help either, text is still blurry when launched by double-click. Launching from terminal presumably uses JDK 19 in my PATH.

Comment: I just replaced JDK 1.8 in `HKCR\jarfile\shell\open\command` with JDK 19 and the problem fixed itself. I think JDK 1.8 installer put that there, and nothing stopped it, since I install JDKs by hand instead of by installer.